# Fragment world position with scale

Tags: three.js

I am trying to get the world position in the fragment shader. I am currently using this in the vertex shader:

```
"varying vec3 vPosition;",
```

...

```
"vPosition = modelViewMatrix * position;",
```

**EDIT**

The variable vPosition is passed into the fragment shader. Essentially I am trying to draw the grid with the red circle wherever the mouse is. The vPosition is then used in the fragment shader to determine if the grid needs to be drawn.

This works great, but not when I scale the mesh. Pls see the images below:

Without scaling:
[image]

With 2X scaling:
[image]

I don't fully understand the whole pipeline. I get the gist of most of it - but I guess what im trying is incorrect...?

**Edit**
This is what the grid drawing code looks like in the fragment shader:

```
// Draw the ring and grid on the terrain for when we are editing it.
"if (show_ring == true){",
   "float distance = sqrt((vPosition.x - ring_center.x) * (vPosition.x - ring_center.x) + (vPosition.z - ring_center.z) * (vPosition.z - ring_center.z));",
   "if (distance < ring_radius + ring_width / 2.0 && distance > ring_radius - ring_width / 2.0) {",
   "gl_FragColor.r += ring_color.r;",
   "gl_FragColor.b += ring_color.b;",
   "gl_FragColor.g += ring_color.g;",
   "gl_FragColor.a += ring_color.a;",
   "gl_FragColor *= 2.0;",
   "gl_FragColor = normalize(gl_FragColor);",                   
"}",

// Grid overlay
"float gridDist = ring_radius / 4.0 * 3.0;",
"if (distance < gridDist ) {",
   "float tiles = 1.0 / 100.0;",
   "float val = mod(vUv.y, tiles);",
   "if (mod(vUv.x, tiles) < .001 || mod(vUv.y, tiles) < .001) {",
   "gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (distance / gridDist);",
   "gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;",
"}",
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the 'worldPosition':

"vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",

Comment: this doesn't seem to take into account translation